# How to navigate to a ConnectionSettingsTask page when the application loads

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have created a secondary tile for the Wifi option under `ConnectionSettingsTask`.

This secondary tile uses the MainPage `NavigatedTo` event to check if the secondary tile was pressed, and if so then navigates to the WiFi page.

The problem is, this will not pass the certification process. If a secondary tile is pressed, that page has to be navigated to, and then when the hardware back button is pressed, the start screen must show.

I do not know how to actually implement this requirement in this way because the `ConnectionSettingsTask` has its own `Show()` method and I do not have access to the `Uri` directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry.aspx)

The idea is - you remove MainPage from navigation history, and then, by back button user can close the application as expected.

Some example [here](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/07/13/removing-the-backstack-entry-in-windows-phone/).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is though is that the ConnectionSettingsTask wifi page is not in my application, but is called by `connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi; connectionSettingsTask.Show();` in my OnNavigatedTo event on MainPage when the secondary tile launches the application. Therefore, `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry` does not work because the only place I can use that is on my MainPage. Is there a way to directly navigate to the wifi page without first navigating to MainPage, perhaps checking if the secondary tile was clicked in another place?

Comment: When you navigates back from settings page try this hack (http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2011/11/mango-sample-exit-application.html) to exit from the app